# How to join values of two arrays using underscoreJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

let's say that we have two arrays:

```
var a = ['Tomo', 'Joseph','Alan'];
var b = ['Brzica', 'Smith', 'Adams'];
```

How to merge these arrays using undersoreJS (or plain javascript if underscore is not the way to do it) to get:

```
c=['Tomo Brzica','Joseph Smith', 'Alan Adams']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
c = _.map(a, function (item, index) {
   return item + " " + b[index];
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
c = _.map(_.zip(a, b), function (elem) {
    return elem.join(" ");
});
```